# Errors running builder 'Flex' on project

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

This is driving me crazy. When building a project, I get the following error

```
Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Flex' on project 'my-services'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here's the last error from the Error log in Eclipse

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2011-09-07 16:07:04.391
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 75 2011-09-07 16:07:04.391
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Flex' on project 'my-services'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.calcBuildTotalWork(FlexProjectBuilder.java:148)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.build(FlexProjectBuilder.java:160)
    at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexIncrementalBuilder.build(FlexIncrementalBuilder.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I've tried cleaning the project, refreshing the project, restarting eclipse, even deleting it from my workspace and re-importing it. I am still lost.

Comment: Are you using Flash Builder?  Which version of Flash Builder are you using?  Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?  You mentioned importing a workspace.  Have you tried creating a new work space w/ your new version of Flash Builder and re-creating your proejcts from scratch?  I added the Flash Builder tag to this post.

Comment: @Flextras Careful - it could just be an old package name that hasn't been changed yet, but the stack trace says 'flexbuilder'.

Comment: @Pasha Is this Flex Builder 3 (plugin) or other? It kinda looks like your IDE is screwed up, but I suppose it could be a bad workspace too. You didn't make any recent changes leading up to this issue?

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall flash builder.  Plugin can be unreliable sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am working with modules and I created a special output folder for all modules. I received this in the log :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2012-03-04 10:27:12.328
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 4 75 2012-03-04 10:27:12.328
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Flex' on project 'myProject'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I was able to resolve it by editing the .project file - which looked causing the error like this:

```
...
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>[source path] modules</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/modules</locationURI>
    </link>
    <link>
        <name>bin-debug</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/modules</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
...
```

I was able to resolve it by editing the .project file - which looked causing the error like this:

```
...
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>bin-debug</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>DOCUMENTS/modules</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
...
```

Hope this helps somebody else solving this annoying error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause for this was that folder where the project was located did not have the **.actionScriptProperties** file in it.

In case you cannot find this file anywhere this is how mine looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actionScriptProperties mainApplicationPath="YOUR_MAIN_SCREEN.mxml" version="3">
<compiler additionalCompilerArguments="-locale en_US -use-network=false" copyDependentFiles="true" enableModuleDebug="false" generateAccessible="false" htmlExpressInstall="true" htmlGenerate="true" htmlHistoryManagement="true" htmlPlayerVersion="9.0.0" htmlPlayerVersionCheck="true" outputFolderPath="bin" strict="true" useApolloConfig="false" verifyDigests="true" warn="true">
<compilerSourcePath/>
<libraryPath defaultLinkType="1">
<libraryPathEntry kind="4" path="">
<modifiedEntries>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/framework.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
</modifiedEntries>
<excludedEntries>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_agent.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/qtp.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_dmv.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
</excludedEntries>
</libraryPathEntry>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="bin"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="bin/libs"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="libs"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="Components/ComponentsTesoreria"/>
</libraryPath>
<sourceAttachmentPath>
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/datavisualization.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/framework.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
</sourceAttachmentPath>
</compiler>
<applications>
<application path="YOUR_MAIN_SCREEN.mxml"/>
<application path="ANOTHER_SCREEN.mxml"/>
</applications>
<modules/>
<buildCSSFiles/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actionScriptProperties mainApplicationPath="YOUR_MAIN_SCREEN.mxml" version="3">
<compiler additionalCompilerArguments="-locale en_US -use-network=false" copyDependentFiles="true" enableModuleDebug="false" generateAccessible="false" htmlExpressInstall="true" htmlGenerate="true" htmlHistoryManagement="true" htmlPlayerVersion="9.0.0" htmlPlayerVersionCheck="true" outputFolderPath="bin" strict="true" useApolloConfig="false" verifyDigests="true" warn="true">
<compilerSourcePath/>
<libraryPath defaultLinkType="1">
<libraryPathEntry kind="4" path="">
<modifiedEntries>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/framework.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
</modifiedEntries>
<excludedEntries>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_agent.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/qtp.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/automation_dmv.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
</excludedEntries>
</libraryPathEntry>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="bin"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="bin/libs"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="libs"/>
<libraryPathEntry kind="1" linkType="1" path="Components/ComponentsTesoreria"/>
</libraryPath>
<sourceAttachmentPath>
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/datavisualization.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/flex.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
<sourceAttachmentPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/libs/framework.swc" sourcepath="${PROJECT_FRAMEWORKS}/source" useDefaultLinkType="true"/>
</sourceAttachmentPath>
</compiler>
<applications>
<application path="YOUR_MAIN_SCREEN.mxml"/>
<application path="ANOTHER_SCREEN.mxml"/>
</applications>
<modules/>
<buildCSSFiles/>
</actionScriptProperties>
```

If you had a REPOSITORY linked to this project this can explain why this is happening
http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2009/02/22/error-loading-project-missing-project-files/